# Can QGIS place diagrams in map legend?

Tags: qgis, legend

I have this map [image]

and I want to put these red circles in the legend of the map according to this form:
[image]

Is there a way to do that in QGIS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *QGIS can not produce a legend like the right one on your color plate 1.2. There is a currently outstanding [feature request](https://hub.qgis.org/issues/4450) to add size-scaled features to the legend in print composer, but it has not
>   yet been implemented. Best try would be to generate it in a third
>   party software or some drawing application, and then add the legend as
>   an image to the print composer layout.*

The request is already some time implemented. You can find it in layer Properties->Diagrams->Legend
Enable *Show Legend...*  and Define style clicking the button:
[image]

Comment: since the last legend refactoring could be possible, theoretically, add everything to the legend... and doing configurable via plugin. Remember that the legend is based on a QTreeView. But the answer is correct... now is not natively implemented. Are you interested in finance it's implementation?

Comment: Actually it's almost landed in QGIS already - there's an outstanding pull request (https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/1977) which is being worked on. Should be ready in development builds shortly.